# Laravel 4 deleted migration

Tags: php, git, laravel, migration

I have deleted 2 migration files, committed and pushed the changes. Now when I try to run the `artisan migrate` command I get an error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
There are no commands defined in the "xyz" namespace.
```

I also can't do `artisan migration:rollback` because I get an error

```
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError","message":"Class 'ClassNameXYZ' not found","file":"....vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Database\/Migrations\/Migrator.php","line":301}}
```

So now I tried running `composer dump-autoload` and all the `artisan` commands about clearing the cache, but when I try to migrate I get the same thing.

I can't drop the database as this will need to be merged on production branch so if I leave it like this and drop and reseed the database it will just break on production server.

I tried adding the deleted migration manually and then `composer dump-autoload`, but I still get the same error when I tried to rollback.

I also wanted to fetch back deleted migrations from previous commit, and did this:

```
git checkout __COMMIT__ __FILENAME__
```

but I get two errors, either:

```
error: pathspec '__FILENAME__' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

or:

```
fatal: __FILENAME__: '__FILENAME__' is outside repository
```

How can I fix this?

**EDIT**

I thought about doing a `git reset` but unfortunately the commit in question is one before last. Last commit is merge of the branch which no longer exists so if I reset it, I will lose changes merged with last branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an error. It was due to migration calling a custom `artisan` command which had a different name from the last time I committed the changes.

I still don't know why git issue is happening, but now it is not crucial.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should follow below comment:

If you deleting a migration class file (xyz), simply delete the record from the **migrations** table. and after you run the command `php artisan migrate`.

Comment: If I do that, I will have to do the same on the production server, which at this point is not an option

Comment: @Norgul: Because this class added in migrations table so may be every time affect